When will the item shop in town open?
When I stop by the item shop in the Town area, the Koopa tells me they aren't open yet but they will open soon. I've completed several mini games, but the shop is still closed.
When does the shop in the Town area open?


The item shop in town (Known as Junk) is only open during three specific missions. These are Nerd Force V, Find the Password, and Bestest Buds. The shop will be closed if you visit while one of these missions isn't active.
